# How can I calculate average with condition in sql

Tags: sql

I would like to calculate average in sql. I have following record in table.

> Let table name = frarecord

[image]

> In above table every column is NOT NULL. Like @peepa mentioned in comment we can identify which start event goes together with which end event  by identifier.

I want to calculate the average of timestamps with following condition.

> case  when eventid=5 then timestamps end as starttime,
>
> case  when eventid=6 then timestamps end as endtime

Now

> time = endTime - startTime.

and

> avg(time) as average

**EDIT:** Timestamps is millseconds not sql timestamps.
I tried to use following queries to separate startTime and endTime

Query1:

```
select 
case  when f.eventid=5 then f.timestamps end as starttime,
case  when f.eventid=6 then f.timestamps end as endtime
from frarecord f
```

and Query2:

```
select f1.timestamps as starttime, f2.timestamps as endtime
from frarecord f
left join frarecord f1 on (f1.id=f.id and f.eventid=5)
left join frarecord f2 on (f2.id=f.id and f.eventid=6)
```

and got following output.

[image]

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: And you're really using MySQL, MS SQL Server and Oracle here??? (Don't tag products not involved... Especially since those 3 products handle date/time in their own ways.)

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  You have enough rep that you should know better than to stuff inappropriate tags on questions.

Comment: I added more tags so that this question can reach to many users. :)

Comment: Its ok @GordonLinoff no problem.

Comment: @jarlh bro I am using Redshift.

Comment: I think you're missing information how you link together the records for start and finish events. As the table is shown, you do not have information that links the rows together so far.

Comment: how it seems from the data, the id is unique id, you need to have something like the transaction id by which you identify which start event goes together with which end event.

Comment: @peepa Yes there is a column  name as `identifier` that identify which start event goes together with which end event. I can group by this identifier. I am sorry that I forgot to mention it in my original questiin.

Comment: @peepa I added new record in first picture you can see. I can identify which start event goes together with which end event by *identifier*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I group all record by `identifier` and separate `starttime` and `endtime`  using following query with the help of *Gordon Linoff*. Answer is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354229/how-can-i-use-group-by-clause-correctly-in-sql/35354242#35354242).

Query I used:

```
with f1 as (
  select (case when f.eventid=5 then f.timestamps end) as starttime,
         (case when f.eventid=6 then f.timestamps end) as endtime,
        f.instanceidentifier as identifier,
        f.formid as formid, 
        f.formname as formname
  from frarecord f  
 )
select min(starttime) as starttime, max(endtime) as endtime, identifier
from f1
group by identifier
```

After running above query I got following output:

[image]

Now I can calculate average time after subtracting following way (I got time that took to complete).

> time = endTime - startTime

Full query to calculate average is given below.

```
select   AVG (endtime-starttime) as average from
(
with f1 as (
  select (case when f.eventid=5 then f.timestamps end) as starttime,
         (case when f.eventid=6 then f.timestamps end) as endtime,
        f.instanceidentifier as identifier,
        f.formid as formid, 
        f.formname as formname
  from frarecord f   
 )
select min(starttime) as starttime, max(endtime) as endtime, identifier
from f1
group by identifier
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is what you are after but its probably the best I could come up with due to the data provided, this assumes you can only have one 'formname' running at one time.
This is not a complete answer but may be a step in the right direction ?

```
;with tablecte as (
select 
case  when f.eventid=5 then f.timestamps end as starttime,
case  when f.eventid=6 then f.timestamps end as endtime,
f.formname
from frarecord f 
order by ISNULL(starttime,endtime)

--select f1.timestamps as starttime, f2.timestamps as endtime
--from frarecord f
--left join frarecord f1 on (f1.id=f.id and f.eventid=5)
--left join frarecord f2 on (f2.id=f.id and f.eventid=6)

), combine as (

select  t2.starttime, (select top 1 t1.endtime from tablecte t1 where t1.endtime > t2.starttime and t1.formname = t2.formname) as endtime from tablecte t2


)
select AVG(starttime - endtime) from combine
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will see your answer in detail tomorrow.