# How can I use group by clause correctly in sql

Tags: sql

I used following query to get expected output but did not work properly.

```
with f1 as 
(
    select 
        case when f.eventid = 5 then f.timestamps end as starttime,
        case when f.eventid = 6 then f.timestamps end as endtime,
        f.instanceidentifier as identifier
    from 
        frarecord f 
)
select 
    starttime, endtime, identifier 
from f1
```

I got following output:

[image]

But output should come with group by identifier.

I also tried to use group by clause for identifier. Exception says me to group by starttime and endtime too.

Is there any solution?

**Note:** This question is closely related with [How can I calculate average with condition in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340928/how-can-i-calculate-average-with-different-condition-in-sql) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using aggregation:

```
with f1 as (
      select (case when f.eventid=5 then f.timestamps end) as starttime,
             (case when f.eventid=6 then f.timestamps end) as endtime,
            f.instanceidentifier as identifier
      from frarecord f
     )
select min(starttime) as starttime, max(endtime) as enddtime, identifier
from f1
group by identifier;
```

Comment: it is working but I have question. Why are you using `min` and `max`, can you explain?

Comment: @Yubaraj . . . Because you need aggregation functions for an aggregation query.